# Is it eins or einz?

Tags: pronunciation

The phonetic transcription of the word **eins** is [ain**s**] but in many cases (to my non-native ears), it is actually pronounced as [ain**ts**] even in the German textbook. So which one is correct?

Comment: As far I know, it is dialect dependent. As far I know, in the southern parts of the country, "ai" is more popular.

Comment: Related Linguistics SE questions: [Is there any epenthesis in German by which “eins” sounds like “eints” and how frequent is the phenomenon?](https://linguistics.stackexchange.com/questions/28384), [Do fricatives turn into affricates after nasal consonants, and why?](https://linguistics.stackexchange.com/questions/6574)

Answer (score 8, accepted):

Notice how the *n* phoneme is formed exactly like the *t* phoneme, that is by pushing your tongue against your upper front teeth. That's your explanation for the ambiguity and the reason why there is no "right" or "wrong" here. It's just different spellings that result in a very similar formation of sounds.

Comment: So the T sound is normal to hear, right?

Comment: Exactly, it's just a physiological result of going from "n" to "s". Whether or not it's audible depends more on the consistency of your saliva than on anything else ;-)

Comment: There is an obvious difference between the two pronunciations. A nice explanation can be found in one of the Linguistics SE questions linked above.